# What's meaning of this?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**"I have certain players who I look up to massively, but you have to remember there are so many variables that judging yourself against other people is quite dangerous. The only person I should judge myself against is myself.**

Comment: Well, what specifically are you having trouble understanding in this quote?

Answer (score 3):

**To look up to** someone means to **admire** and to **respect** them as a human being, for what they have done or for what they stand for.

Here, the person means that she has players she admires, but that you still have to keep in mind there are too many criterias to judge a man. For example, even if Bruno Mars might be a better singer than you, you can't straight-up feel bad for it as you surely have qualities he doesn't have.

The last sentence is open to interpretation, but I would understand that as "be your own best without minding too much about the others", through **introspection** and finding who you really are based on who you were, and who you aspire to be.